# How to keep corporate Blackberry devices "on time"?

Tags: blackberry, bes, time-synchronization, securid

Does anybody know if the BES Server has any option to "provide" the time to the devices on sync?

The issue here is, we have users travelling to other Time Zones who are changing the TIME of the BB instead of the TZ, but that's playing havoc with things such as calendars, etc and will impact a future deployment of Software-based SecurID tokens.

Now, if there was a way to have BES provide the time (a-la NTP), the user would have/be limited to changing the time zone, and that's something the devices/software can live with

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the device itself you can select the option to sync to the blackberry time source from inside the Date/Time settings.

There is not settings in the IT Policy to force these settings however. [Reference Guide for BES IT Policy](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/IT_Policy_Reference_Guide.pdf?func=doc.Fetch&nodeId=1139948&docTitle=IT+Policy+Reference+Guide)

Comment: This appears, on my Blackberry Pearl and the 7250 I had before, a one-time sync.  The device does not continue to sync, you have to manually re-sync it periodically.  I have not found a work-around.

Comment: Another colleague suggested to use "network time", but again, not in all the countries/all operators offer "time" in their networks.

Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to push the time to the devices. Here is a [KB](http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB10559&sliceId=2&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&dialogID=154973334&stateId=0%200%20154971616) about the BB time.  It's a one time setting and it doesn't automaticly keep itself up to date (I have no idea why since every other cell phone in the world seems to).  The only thing you can do is user education, I've had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I've had a look at it and it seems that I'm out of luck. I hope there is a way to "set" this via the BB server, but if it's not something the device will check periodically, then I'm out of luck.

Best

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called AtomicClock from the company ORBIT (http://www.orbit.de) that should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any option for this.  I didn't see an option to disable the users ability to change the clock either.